# Get ProgressBar Value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, progress-bar

I am Trying to implement a `ProgressBar` in WPF and figured it would be nice to show the percentage as a percentage on the bar itself.

I found out that the `ProgressBar` conveniently already does calculations for the display in the background. So let's say I have a **max value of 12** and the **current value is 6**, is shows a progress bar which is already **half/50% full**.

[image: ProgessBar that is half filled.]

Unfortunately the value of the `ProgressBar` is still 6 (because it is the sixth element of 12)

[image: ProgessBar that is half filled with an overlay text that says "6%".]

Is there an easy way to get the percentage value of the progress bar, or do I have to do the calculations on my own and databind a `double` variable to the `TextBox` and `ProgressBar`?

This is the XAML code I have so far:

```
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid Margin="20">
                <ProgressBar Name="ProgrBar"  Minimum="0" Maximum="12" Value="6" Height="30"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ProgrBar, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0}% }" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I think ValueConverter is necessary in your case because `Maximum` is not 100

Comment: My preference would be to let whatever component that reports the progress specify the description text. In many cases I find it more useful to report "6/12" than using percentages, that makes it easier for the operator to check that progress is being made when there are a large number of items.

Comment: You need to calculate it at some place: viewmodel, converter or custom control derived from ProgressBar ...

Answer (score 0):

The `ProgressBar` does not know how to display percentages. It has a `Minimum` and a `Maximum` property that only define the bounds within the `Value` is expected. All are of type `double`, but their interpretation is up to you. It could be percentages, steps in a process, number of items, you name it.

If the percentage is data from a model in your context, you could expose it from the view model, but if it is only for display purposes, you could create a value converter that takes the limits and value and returns a formatted percentage string.

```
public class PercentageConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (values.Length != 3 ||
          !(values[0] is double minimum) ||
          !(values[1] is double maximum) ||
          !(values[2] is double value) ||
          minimum > maximum ||
          value < minimum ||
          value > maximum)
         return Binding.DoNothing;

      var percentage = (value - minimum) / (maximum - minimum);
      return percentage.ToString("P0");
   }

   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

The converter is a multi-value converter to be able to bind multiple properties. It checks the bounds before calculation to rule out weird results in case of invalid input. The format specifier is `P0`.

- [Percent format specifier (P)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#percent-format-specifier-p)

Create an instance of the converter in a resource dictionary in scope and use it in a [`MultiBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.multibinding?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

```
<Grid Margin="20">
   <Grid.Resources>
      <local:PercentageConverter x:Key="PercentageConverter"/>
   </Grid.Resources>
   <ProgressBar Name="ProgrBar"  Minimum="0" Maximum="12" Value="6" Height="30"/>
   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">
      <TextBlock.Text>
         <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PercentageConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="ProgrBar" Path="Minimum"/>
            <Binding ElementName="ProgrBar" Path="Maximum"/>
            <Binding ElementName="ProgrBar" Path="Value"/>
         </MultiBinding>
      </TextBlock.Text>
   </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

---

Since this is a type of control that you might want to reuse, you could think about extracting it into a `UserControl` or even custom control if you want to enable templating. Then you could make the display of results toggleable with a property, e.g. `DisplayPercentage` or allow for custom converters similar to this one. This could prevent a lot of copy-paste and duplicated code in the long run, keep it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

- [Control authoring overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to get the percentage value of the progress bar

No, because it's not stored somewhere.

> or do I have to do the calculations on my own ...

Yes. Bind the `TextBlock` to a property that returns the value of the expression `ProgrBar.Maximum / ProgrBar.Value`.